# Freak Bower Failure

Tags: bower

Does anyone know if this simply means that the Bower server is temporarily down?  Freaky having that external dependency!

```
$ bower install

bower EINVRES       Request to https://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/angular-route failed with 503
```

**NOTE:** By the time this writing was finished, problem had gone away.

Still, any ideas on how to mitigate the risk of development being blocked by Bower going down?

Comment: "Error 503: The Web server (running the Web site) is currently unable to handle the HTTP request due to a temporary overloading or maintenance of the server. The implication is that this is a temporary condition which will be alleviated after some delay." In this case, find a mirror, or have on hand back up files.

Comment: Thanks @DeadChex yes all signs point to implementing our own (hosted in-shop) redundancy for all dependencies!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Error 503: The Web server (running the Web site) is currently unable to handle the HTTP request due to a temporary overloading or maintenance of the server. The implication is that this is a temporary condition which will be alleviated after some delay.

In this case, find a mirror, or have on hand back up files.